# Windows 8.1 - How to get the index of elements when binding a CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, collectionviewsource

I have a Windows 8.1 application.

My CollectionViewSource is a list of items which is grouped by date when the items were created. Now I have binded this CollectionViewSource to a ListView so as to display the group headers for each group and then the corresponding values.

Let's say I have 3 groups as follows

```
September 1
    Item-1
    Item-2
    Item-3
September 2
    Item-4
    Item-5
September 3
    Item 6
```

Now I want to display alternate items in each group with alternate backgrounds.
If Item-1 is black, then Item-2 is white, Item-3 is black. Since Item-4 is in group 2 it is again black and so on. If I get the index of each element in each group, I can do this alternate backgrounds using a converter. How do I get the index?

Here is my xaml of my ListViewItemTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyListViewItemTemplate">
    <Grid Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource alternateListItemBackgroundConverter}}">
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

What should I bind in the above xaml to get the index which I can use in my converter as shown below. Here is my Convert function of the converter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    int index = value as int;
    if (value == null || !int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out index))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The value passed to this converter must be an integer value", "value");
    }
    return index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.Black : Colors.White;
}
```

I would be very glad if someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution might be to set the index property value in the grouping function or whatever it is you use to group the items or generate the collection view.